# Plotting a bipartite tree graph

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to plot a generalized version of this graph in Mathematica[image]

I already have a code where you give a number(for the above graph the number would be 4) and it returns a matrix that gives this type of graph in any size using the `AdjacencyGraph` function, but it doesn't plot it the way I want. It comes out like this:[image]

I will include my code that gives the matrix and the graph. I hope its not too confusing, it was written this way because I need to work with individual points in the graph.

The numbering system I used is "j" for the column and "i" for the lines. For example, the "j=3" column has 4 "i's", from 1 to 4, and for n=4 there are 9 possible values for j.

`

```
n = 4;

js = Table[i, {i, 1, 2 n + 1}];

nis = Table[

   If[i <= n + 1, 2^(js[[i]] - 1),
    2^(2 n - (js[[i]] - 1))
    ]

   , {i, 1, 2 n + 1}];

kets = {};

Do[AppendTo[kets, Table[{js[[j]], i}, {i, 1, nis[[j]]}]], {j, 1, 
  2 n + 1}]

links[{j_, i_}] :=

  If[j != 1 && j != 2 n + 1 && j != n + 1 && j < n + 1,
   {
    If[Divisible[i - 1, 2],
     {kets[[j - 1, (i - 1)/2 + 1]]}
     , {kets[[j - 1, i/2]]}]
    , {kets[[j + 1, 2 (i - 1) + 1]]},
    {kets[[j + 1, 2 (i - 1) + 2]]}
    },

   If[j == 1,
    {{kets[[j + 1, i]]}, {kets[[j + 1, i + 1]]}},

    If[j == 2 n + 1,
     {{kets[[j - 1, i]]}, {kets[[j - 1, i + 1]]}},

     If[j == n + 1,

      {If[Divisible[i - 1, 2],
        {kets[[j - 1, (i - 1)/2 + 1]]}
        , {kets[[j - 1, i/2]]}]
       , If[Divisible[i - 1, 2],
        {kets[[j + 1, (i - 1)/2 + 1]]}
        , {kets[[j + 1, i/2]]}]},
      If[j != 1 && j != 2 n + 1 && j != n + 1 && j > n + 1,
       {
        If[Divisible[i - 1, 2],
         {kets[[j + 1, (i - 1)/2 + 1]]}
         , {kets[[j + 1, i/2]]}]
        , {kets[[j - 1, 2 (i - 1) + 1]]},
        {kets[[j - 1, 2 (i - 1) + 2]]}
        }
       ]
      ] 
     ] 
    ]
   ];

int[{j1_, i1_}, {j2_, i2_}] := 1.0;

matElem[ket_] := Module[{lin},
   lin = Flatten[links[ket], 1];
   Table[{ket /. rep, lin[[i]] /. rep} -> int[ket, lin[[i]]], {i, 
     Length@lin}]
   ];

f[x_] := If[x != 0, 1, 0];

kets2 = Flatten[kets, 1];

d = Length@kets2;

list = Range[1, d];

rep = Thread[kets2 -> list];

H = SparseArray[Flatten[Table[matElem[ket], {ket, kets2}], 1], {d, d}]

AdjacencyGraph[Map[f, Normal@H, {2}]]
```

`

Comment: Have you tried playing with `GraphLayout`?

Comment: @Kuba I have and none of them worked. What "almost" worked was plotting half the graph, but only to a certain size, then it would mess up again...

Comment: Now I noticed that I didn't try all of them and some of them come really close actually, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A different approach starting from scratch.  *Now corrected for n > 4*.

Even if you don't use my rather hackish visualization construction `f2` may be useful to you.

```
f1[p_, 0] := p
f1[p_, lev_] := (Scan[Sow @ {p, f1[2 p + #, lev - 1]} &, {0, 1}]; p)

f2[n_] := Reap[ f1[1, n] ][[2, 1]];

el = f2[5];
vc = GraphEmbedding @ Graph[el, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"];
Graph[el, VertexCoordinates -> vc.{{1, 0}, {0, #}}] & /@ {3.5, -3.5};
Show[%] // Rotate[#, 90 °] &
```

[image]

- The values `{3.5, -3.5}` control the aspect ratio, e.g. for different *n* values.

---

My answer feels incomplete without a way to generate an actual and complete `Graph`.
Here is a solution somewhat less clean than I would like but functional.

```
n = 4;
el = f2[n];
vc = GraphEmbedding @ Graph[el, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"];

el2 = Join[el, Mod[el, 2^(n + 1) - 1, 2^n]];
vc2 = Join[vc, Drop[vc, -(2^n)].{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}].{{0, -1}, {-2, 0}};

Graph[el2
  , VertexCoordinates -> vc2
  , VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]
  , VertexLabelStyle -> 16
  , VertexSize -> 0
]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very nice solution and the graph looks perfect up to n=4. I can't use it for the main purpose of my project but i will definitely use it on the report. Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro I must admit I forgot to test this beyond n=4 and didn't see that it failed.  I'll try to return to this later and see if I can extend it.  Anyway I hope the `f2` function proves to be a useful base for further experimentation.

Comment: @Pedro Please see my updated answer.  I just needed `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"` for that part of it.  Regarding *I can't use it for the main purpose of my project* why is that?  Perhaps I can improve this further.

Comment: "Perhaps I can improve this further". I can't imagine how you could improve this code, it works perfectly now. The reason why I believed I wouldn't be able to use this code is that I couldn't get an AdjacencyMatrix from it combined with the fact that I already invested a lot of time in these few days using my original construction of the graph.

I'll mark your answer as the accepted one because it does what I asked exactly. Thanks for willing to help further but I believe that in the stage I am in my project it's too late to change my code. But rest assured that f2 will be used.

Answer (score 14):

Not exactly the same but similar layout:

```
g = AdjacencyGraph[Map[f, Normal@H, {2}], 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

Modify coords to get better shape:

```
emb = GraphEmbedding[g];
emb[[All, 1]] = 
  1.2 Divide @@ 
    Reverse[Differences[CoordinateBoundingBox[emb]][[1]]] emb[[All, 1]];

Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> emb, PlotTheme -> "BasicBlack", VertexSize -> .6]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Slightly factored version of the original function to generate the `VertexCoordinates` and the `AdjacencyMatrix`  to be used in `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
ClearAll[vcF, amF, karyAdjG]
vcF[n_, base_] := Module[{layers = base^Join @@ Range[{0, n - 1}, {n, 0}, {1, -1}], 
   hsize, divs, ycoords},
  hsize = Length[layers] - 1;
  divs = Range[-hsize/2, hsize/2, hsize/(base^n - 1)];
  ycoords = Flatten@{Reverse@#, Rest@#} &@
    NestList[Developer`PartitionMap[N@Mean@# &, #, base] &, divs, n];
  Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, Internal`PartitionRagged[ycoords, layers]]]

amF[n_, base_] := Module[{layers = base^(Join@@Range[{0, n - 1}, {n, 0}, {1, -1}]), r, c},
  r = Total[layers[[;; n]]]; c = Total[layers[[;; n + 1]]];
  # + Transpose[#] &@ SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}, {r, c}] -> {{Table[1, {base}]}},
        Band[{1, 1} + {r, c}, {-1, -1}] -> {Table[{1}, {base}]}}, (r + c) {1, 1}]]

karyAdjG[n_, base_, aspect_: 1][opts___ : OptionsPattern[Graph]] :=
 AdjacencyGraph[amF[n, base], VertexCoordinates -> ({1, aspect} # & /@ vcF[n, base]), opts]
```

Example:

```
karyAdjG[3, 4][VertexStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black], 
 EdgeStyle -> Thickness[Large], EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:** Also from scratch, generalizing to arbitrary k-ary layered network:

```
ClearAll[karyG]
karyG[n_, base_, aspect_: 1][opts___ : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
     Module[{layers = base^Join @@ Range[{0, n - 1}, {n, 0}, {1, -1}], 
  ycoords, vertcoords, vlist, parts, elist, divs, hsize},
 hsize = Length[layers] - 1;
 divs = Range[-hsize/2, hsize/2, hsize/(base^n - 1)];
 ycoords = Flatten@{Reverse@#, Rest@#} &@
   NestList[Developer`PartitionMap[N@Mean@# &, #, base] &, divs, n];
 vertcoords = Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[ycoords, layers]];
 vlist = Range@Total@layers;
 parts = Partition[Internal`PartitionRagged[vlist, layers], 2, 1];
 elist = Sort /@ (Flatten@(Thread /@ Thread[# <-> Partition[#2, base]] & @@@ 
       MapAt[Reverse, parts, {1 + n ;;}]));
 Graph[elist, VertexCoordinates -> ({1, aspect} # & /@ vertcoords), opts]]
```

Examples:

```
ops = Sequence[VertexStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.02], Black], EdgeStyle -> Thick, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", ImageSize -> 400];

karyG[#, #2][ops, PlotLabel->Style[Row[{"n = ", #, ", base = ", #2}], "Panel", 16]]& @@@ 
  {{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}} // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
karyG[#, #2][ops, PlotLabel->Style[Row[{"n = ", #, ", base = ", #2}], "Panel", 16]]& @@@ 
  {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}} // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[{karyG[7, 2][ops], karyG[3, 5][ops]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The optional third argument (with default value 1) controls the aspect ratio:

```
Row[{karyG[4, 2, 1][ops], karyG[4, 2, 1/2][ops]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Vertices are ordered left-to-right and bottom-to-up:

```
karyG[4, 2][EdgeStyle -> Thick, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 ImageSize -> 400, VertexStyle -> White, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold], VertexSize -> .75, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]